# Javascript only web service call

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In Dynamics CRM, I have a javascript file that needs to call an external web service (cross domain). This is a pure JS file; no HTML.

JQUERY cannot be used here (Dynamics limitation) so I need to call the cross domain web service through java script alone.

Does anyone have a example of calling a cross domain web service with javascript alone?

JSONP doesn't seem to work since I can't use an HTML element inside the file.

Comment: Since this is apparently not a browser, you will have to see what types of ajax APIs your environment has.  None are built-in to Javascript itself.  For example, modern browsers use `fetch()`, you would use `XMLHttpRequest` in older browsers and you would use the `http` library in node.js.

Comment: HTML WebResources can be treated like any other HTML pages. CRM does not impose any limitations on the use of jQuery or other libraries on web resources. Add jQuery as a javascript web resource and reference it on your HTML page, makes your life so much easier. CRM only recommends not to use jQuery for DOM manipulations on the actual CRM forms, not web resources.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM can an HTML page be used with an onChange event? I only see JS resources as options

Comment: Use `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource(webResourceName)` launch an html page, ask the user to click a button to update the record, use jQuery to fetch the data and update the parent window's attribute value, if you are too worried about referencing jQuery on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in C# code: create an Action, either register a plugin to it or make the code a Code Activity, then invoke the Action from JS. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607600.aspx for details on invoking actions from the WebAPI.

In the C# code, you're free to use i.e. `WebClient` to communicate with outside world (see a sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509030.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Fetch is a native way for your browser to request HTTP resources. However, it isn't supported on older browsers so you could use a polyfill if you want to support these browsers.

If you wanna call cross domain, you should call fetch with this option set:

```
fetch('http://domain.example/', { mode: 'cors' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Sys.Net.WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310979.aspx). This library is used by MS Dynamics CRM 2016 to perform its Web API requests. It's referenced in their Microsoft.Ajax.js resource. Therefore, you don't need to reference it in your `.js` Web Resource.

You can find usage examples on the the [Sys.Net.WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310979.aspx) page. Here is an example of how to call a Dynamics CRM Action using this library:

```
var kaId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");

var wr = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
wr.set_url(myCustomGetWebApiUrl() + "knowledgearticles(" + kaId + ")/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.new_MyCustomBoundAction");
wr.set_httpVerb("POST");
wr.set_body(null);
var headers = wr.get_headers();
headers["Content-Length"] = 0;
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
headers["OData-Version"] = "4.0";
wr.add_completed(function (executor) {
    var actionResponse = JSON.parse(executor.get_responseData());
    if (actionResponse)
        console.log(actionResponse);
    else
        alert("An error occurred: " + executor.get_statusText());
});

wr.invoke();
```